# Inserting Form values into Database through PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my `etaNavServer.php` file. These are the values I have to insert into database. My table name is `user` and database name is `srilanka`, and these are the values I have to insert.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['continue']))
{
    $eta_type = $_POST['eta_type'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

    $title1=$_POST['title1'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO user(applicationtype,surname,givenname,title,) VALUES 
  ('$eta_type','$lastname','$firstname','$title1')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if($query){
        echo "<h4 style='color:green'>Services Added Successfully.</h4>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "srilanka";
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

?>
```

Comment: so what's your question

Comment: What happened? You just described your codes, but not the problem/s you encountered

Comment: Is the trailing `}` a typo in `connection.php`?

Comment: In addition to that, there's a trailing comma after the columns specifications. Remove that. Voting to close as off-topic because of typo.

Comment: My Form values are not going into the database @Swellar

Comment: What error appeared?

Comment: @Swellar "Failed" occured.

Comment: First of all did you `included` that `connection` file in `etaNavServer.php`

Comment: @JYoThl already did.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in

```
$sql="INSERT INTO user(applicationtype,surname,givenname,title,) VALUES 
  ('$eta_type','$lastname','$firstname','$title1')";
```

remove extra `,` after title

```
$sql="INSERT INTO user(applicationtype,surname,givenname,title) VALUES 
  ('$eta_type','$lastname','$firstname','$title1')";
```

**Note:** You have only closing brace `}` in connection, assuming this is just a typo

**EDIT**

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: trace your and let us know what error you are facing now

Comment: After removing } and and comma still values are not going into the database @Jigar Shah

Comment: check edited line , it will show error if occurred from query

Comment: you should pass connection object as a parameter to `die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: Thanks, I just mixed with another. Updated